# WPF passing data from one window to another

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a program where I am loading data from CSV and I am saving them to List. Then I am loading them to listbox and to texboxes. I created "New" button to add a new item to the List and show new item in the listbox and texboxes. But Everytime I create new item I delete my previous List. Can anyone please help me how to add a new item and keep all my data?

Second window:

```
    public partial class New : Window
    {
    AddDataFromImport data = new AddDataFromImport();
    private string centName;
    private string centCode;
    private string centDesc;

    public New()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(centName,centCode,centDesc);
        mainWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    }
```

Second window XML:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnSave" Content="Save" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Height="30" Click="BtnSave_Click"></Button>
```

Main window:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public AddDataFromImport meetingData = new AddDataFromImport();
    private Centre selectedCentre = null;
    private Room selectedRoom = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(string nameNewCent, string codeNewCent, string descNewCent) : this()
    {
        Centre cent = new Centre(nameNewCent, codeNewCent, descNewCent);
        meetingData.MeetingCentres.Add(cent);
        ListOfCentres.ItemsSource = meetingData.MeetingCentres;
    }

    private void SelectCheck(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
    }

    // Load import
    private void ImportData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result = openFileDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            var filename = openFileDlg.FileName;
            meetingData.CreateDataStrucuturtes(filename);
            ListOfCentres.ItemsSource = meetingData.MeetingCentres;
        }
    }

    // Fill center columns
    public void ListOfCentres_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedCentre = (Centre)ListOfCentres.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedCentre != null)
        {
            TBoxName.Text = selectedCentre.Name;
            TBoxCode.Text = selectedCentre.Code;
            TBoxDescription.Text = selectedCentre.Description;
        }
    }

    // Fill rooms from selected centre
    private void TBoxName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Centre)ListOfCentres.SelectedItem != null)
            ListOfRooms.ItemsSource = ((Centre)ListOfCentres.SelectedItem).RoomsInCentre;
    }

    // Create new centre
    private void BtnNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        New newWindow = new New();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
    }
```

Main window XML:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="10,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340">
        <ListBox x:Name="ListOfCentres" DisplayMemberPath="CenterName" Height="119" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="340" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Centres}" SelectionChanged="ListOfCentres_SelectionChanged"/>
    </StackPanel>

            <Button x:Name="BtnNew" Content="New" Width="70" Margin="0,5,0,0" Height="21" Click="BtnNew_Click"></Button>
```

[image: WPF]

Comment: Why do you create new main window in dialog? It's not clear what means *" Everytime I create new item I delete my previous List"*. What list? How do you see it's deleted?

Comment: So many issues, it may be too broad. My suggestion would be: Read up on MVVM and repair your design (maybe you'll need to start over).

Comment: As far as I can see, I would totally expect the observed behavior. You create MainWindow Instance1, fill its list. Then you create "New" Instance, which creates a new MainWindow Instance2 (which has en _empty_ meetingData) and add the new entry. So all entries of MainWindow Instance1 are unknown to Instance2.

Comment: Why are you createing a new instance of the main window in the `BtnSave_Click` of your `New` form with this line `MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(centName,centCode,centDesc);` - this creates a new instance of the mainwindow with obvisouly a new list - why do you even try to Show the mainWindow at all since you aren't hiding/closing it

Comment: I see. I couldn't add new data to the List so I tried to create new instance. When I just write in BtnSave_Click: Centre centre = new Centre(name, code, desc);
            MeetingCentres.Add(centre); the list isn't filling.

Comment: Then add right after that `ListOfCentres.ItemsSource = meetingData.MeetingCentres;` let us know if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I **Strongly** recommend you go and learn more of the fundamentals of (not necessarily C#) programming and read up on the MVVM design pattern, but if you really want to do it this way, I wont stop you

A solution (although it may be a bit overkill) is to use a `Callback` method. Basically we give a Method to the Constructor of your `New` window and the execute that function when we want to save the newly created `Centre`

Your New window would look like this:

```
private Action<Centre> _callback;

public New(Action<Centre> callback)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _callback = callback;
}

private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Validate());
    {
        callback(new Centre(centName, centCode, centDesc);
        this.Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Something didn't validate");
}
```

And your MainWindow code would be something like this:

```
private void AddNewCentre(Centre centre)
{
    meetingData.MeetingCentres.Add(centre);
}

private void BtnNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    New newWindow = new New(AddNewCentre);
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

**Explanation:** With `delegates` (like the `Action` we're using) you can pass methods as parameters. And here we're passing the method to add a new Centre to your new view. Once we're done adding a new Centre we `Validate();` (I'm assuming this validates the data that was entered and returns a bool true/ false if the data is correct) and if we successfully do that we call the method we gave as a parameter which adds the new Centre to the list and then close the window

Comment: Actually, OP should use MVVM and live happily everafter.

Comment: @Fildor I understand he should, and I understand that MVVM should be used for WPF, but some people don't have an advanced enough knowledge of C# or programming (yet) to understand patterns. And it seems like OP wants to play around with a GUI without having to use WinForms

Comment: And what would be the benefit in learning how to fiddle a way around doing it correctly over learning how to do it correctly? If OP lacks knowledge, we should encourage and help him to acquire that knowledge. If it's over his head, he should start with something simpler.

Comment: The thing is it's school homework so I have to make it till tomorrow. It's true I am doing this with almost no knowledge of OOP or MVVM.

Comment: @Tatarka learning by doing ;). Also did this help in any way? If not I'm happy to keep providing my assistance here's a chat link so we don't spam up the comments: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183902/room-for-mindswipe-and-tatarka

Comment: @Tatarka Ouch, that's a real tight schedule. In this very special case, try and use this workaround. But be advised that it'll be _very_ low quality. Good luck to you. (No offense , MindSwipe. I mean it in the sense that we agree it _should_ be done differently. But I don't see a complete overhaul with learning MVVM until tomorrow anything near feasable, neither.)

Comment: @Fildor I agree it will be very low quality, but it seems like that's the bar for the course OP is taking. No shame in being new. (No offense taken)